# In ODBC, SQLExecute() returns SQL_NEED_DATA

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, odbc

`SQLExecute()` can be successfully executed without parameters, but with parameters it returns SQL_NEED_DATA. `SQLPrepare()` and `SQLBindParameter()` execute successfully.

```
ret = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hDbc, &hStmt);
SQLSetStmtAttr(hStmt, SQL_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT, (SQLPOINTER)3, 0); 
SQLCHAR* SQLToExe3 = (SQLCHAR*) "INSERT INTO student VALUES(?,?,?)" ;
ret = SQLPrepare(hStmt, SQLToExe3, SQL_NTS);

Test(ret); 
        
SQLCHAR SNOInput[SNO_Len]="2030211892", SNameInput[SName_Len]="zhangxun", SDepartInput[SDepart_Len]="CS";
    
SQLLEN SNOLen,SNameLen2,SDepartLen2;
ret = SQLBindParameter(hStmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_VARCHAR, 20, 0, SNOInput, SNO_Len, &SNOLen);
ret = SQLBindParameter(hStmt, 2, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_VARCHAR, 20, 0, SNameInput, SName_Len, &SNameLen2);
ret = SQLBindParameter(hStmt, 3, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_VARCHAR, 20, 0, SDepartInput, SNO_Len, &SDepartLen2);

ret = SQLExecute(hStmt);// SQLExecute return SQL_INVALID_HANDLE
```

Comment: Function failed due to an invalid environment, connection, statement, or descriptor handle. This indicates a programming error. This code is returned only when the handle is a null pointer or is the wrong type, such as when a statement handle is passed for an argument that requires a connection handle. - from Microsoft docs. Check the return value for success for each of the ODBC API that your code is calling.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: Set the value of parameter StrLen_or_IndPtr of SQLBindParameter() to SQL_NTS